# Meteor OAuth Add/Pass Query Params to /oauth/authenticate (Twitter "force_login")

Tags: meteor

I'm creating a package where I allow to connect multiple same service accounts and I need to force the user to login to the account at the popup window every time (do not authenticate automatically) twitter has the option for "force_login" parameter when using `Meteor.loginWithTwitter`[twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authenticate)

I can't find any way of using it with meteor, I also looked into creating my own twitter/accounts-twitter package but it seems like it's even deeper some where inside oauth packages and it gets really messy to figure out where or how I can do that. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

It was not possible yesterday, but it's possible today. I opened this pull request in the Meteor repository adding this functionality: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/5693

```
Meteor.loginWithTwitter({ force_login: true }, ...);
```

Note it's not merged *yet*, but hopefully it will be soon.